# Как запретить пересоздание Activity при повороте экрана?

Tags: android, activity

Как сделать так, чтобы `Activity` не перезагружалась при смене ориентации экрана?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Activity в AndroidManifest.xml следует объявить, какие события не должны приводить к перезагрузке Activity. Следует поступать так:

```
<activity ... android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
```

Это укажет системе, что не следует перезагружать Activity при смене ориентации/размеров экрана.

Comment: 0xFFh, большое спасибо. Это то что надо было

Answer (score 0):

Тут что то подобное есть: [тут](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/133-urok-70-onsaveinstancestate-sohranenie-dannyh-activity-pri-povorote-ekrana.html)

Comment: тут еще написано про ориентации экрана. http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/orientation.php

Answer (score 0):

в манифесте под тегом Activity напиши **configChange="orientation"**

Answer (score 0):

Можно просто отменить возможную вторую ориентацию..
Можно вот тут мыслей по этому поводу посмотреть:       http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/orientation.php

Comment: Как вручную отменить возможную вторую ориентацию?

Comment: В заголовок описания активити <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" вставить строку:
android:orientation="vertical" (или "horizontal")
Это отменит смену ориентации экрана